# Python module use function defined before import

Tags: python, python-import

I would like to define a bunch of commands in a separate file for tidiness.

```
def cmd1():
    print("calling cmd1")

import define_cmd2

cmd2()
```

And then define_cmd2.py:

```
cmd1()

def cmd2():
    print("called cmd2")
```

It tells me `cmd1()` is not defined. How can I call import so that I can use/edit/call stuff defined before the import call?

Comment: You might think your naming convention here is very smart, but it actually just confuses the reader. Consider re-writing this with good realistic names and proper formatting.

Comment: Please give proper examples for your two files. I can't actually understand which file should be importing what

Comment: is that better?

Comment: That's not how python works. Are you hoping for some sort of reverse-import?

Comment: Where is the `import` statement in `define_commands`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Circular (or cyclic) imports in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/744373/circular-or-cyclic-imports-in-python)

Comment: @MadPhysicist from context it's clear that he expects define_commands to USE the def which is in the file which is importing it....

Comment: @NgOon-Ee. That is not clear to me at all. Nothing is :)

Comment: I would like to import the file and just execute the code in the current scope. Is that possible?

Comment: Why should `cmd1()` be recognised in define_cmd2.py? It looks like your import is the wrong way round. You want to import `cmd1()` into define_cmd2.py

Comment: its an example name, it would actually do something different in my code. I have a bunch of variables and functions defined in the main file. then partway through I need to call the second file to define a bunch of functions, then continue with my code

Comment: Classic XY problem I think. You need to think the question through more thoroughly. The way you wish to do this is not possible (which does not mean you cannot achieve what you actually want to, just that the only answer TO THE QUESTION YOU ACTUALLY ASKED is no).

Comment: @NgOon-Ee. That is why there is an "unclear what you asked" option when closing questions. Just sayin'.

Comment: @MadPhysicist fair enough

Answer (score 0):

A python file (e.g. `define_cmd2.py`) is/should be self-contained. A very basic requirement is that if you wish to use a function named `cmd1`, it MUST be defined either in `define_cmd2.py` or in some file which is imported before you call the function.

However this sounds more like an [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/). What are you actually trying to do?

Comment: I want to execute `define_cmd2.py` in the middle of my code. I am defining a bunch of functions in `define_cmd2.py` and just for tidiness I would like to have them all in a different file.

Comment: Why does define_cmd2 meed cmd1 then? It sounds like define_cmd1 should be a separate file, perhaps imported twice (once in your 'main' and once in define_cmd2. @MadPhysicist answer would be relevant then.

Answer (score 0):

You should first understand how Python imports work a little.

The *first* time you invoke `import` on a module, it gets executed. The resulting namespace, with all function and variable definitions is used to create a module object that is referenced in your namespace, as well as in `sys.modules`. The next time it gets imported, the import just references the existing module from `sys.modules`.

To avoid errors caused by cyclic imports, the module object is actually created first, before the code is run, so that further imports will already see an existing module in `sys.modules` and not attempt to re-execute the same code over and over.

In your particular case, you need to explicitly import `define_cmd2` from `define_cmd1` if you want to use the contents of `define_cmd1`. Secondly, you need to reference the imported names properly:

**define_cmd1**:

```
def cmd1():
    print("calling cmd1")

import define_cmd2

define_cmd2.cmd2()
```

**define_cmd2**

```
import define_cmd1

import define_cmd1.cmd1()

def cmd2():
    print("called cmd2")
```

The bolded items are bits of code you need to add.

To clarify, here is what will happen when you run `define_cmd`:

1. The `def` statement will create a function `define_cmd1.cmd1`.
2. The `import` will attempt to load `define_cmd2`
3. The `import` in `define_cmd2` will do nothing since `sys.modules['define_cmd1']` already exists, meaning that it is loaded or being loaded.
4. `define_cmd1.cmd1()` will run.
5. The `def` statement will create a function `define_cmd2.cmd2`
6. Return to loading `define_cmd1`
7. Run `define_cmd2.cmd2`

Comment: Would execfile work for what I am after? I have heard it is unstable, why is that?

Comment: @ZachMozel. Noone here has any idea of what you are after. You really need to come up with a better example of what you are doing.

Comment: Have you tried what I suggest and had it fail, or are you just asking questions without any application in mind?

Comment: @zachmozel I'm personally struggling to understand why you would want to do this in the first place. If you're separating functions between files "to make things clearer" then when do both functions need to be available in both files? There's no clear execution path to me in your example. Your example now has 2 modules seemingly running the same code.